# Reference request: $C^k(\overline\Omega)$ as restriction of $C^{k}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ functions on $\Omega$

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, notation

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be an open set. $C^k(\Omega)$ is defined as the space of functions $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\partial^nf$ is continuous for $0\leq|n|\leq k$.

There are usually two equivalent definitions for the space $C^k(\overline\Omega)$ one can see in references:
$$
C^k(\overline\Omega)=\{f\in C^k(\Omega)\mid \partial^\alpha f \textrm{  has a continuous extension on } \overline\Omega\textrm{ for }|\alpha|\leq k\}
$$

$$
C^k(\overline\Omega)=\{f\in C^k(\Omega)\mid \partial^\alpha f \textrm{  is uniformly continuous on } \Omega\textrm{ for }|\alpha|\leq k\}
$$
See e.g. Folland's *Introduction to Partial Differential Equations* or Evans's *Partial Differential Equations*. I read somewhere that $C^{k}(\overline\Omega)$ is defined explicitly as the following
$$
C^k(\overline\Omega)=\{g|_\Omega\mid g\in C^k(\mathbb{R}^d)\}.
$$
But I really don't remember where. Could anybody come up with a reference with this definition?

Comment: $\Omega$ is bounded (so that the uniform continuity on $\overline{\Omega}$ follows from the continuity), and all your definition are equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hermann Sohr's *The Navier-Stokes Equations — An Elementary Functional Analytic Approach* (page.23), $C^k(\overline\Omega)$ means the space of all restrictions $u|_{\overline\Omega}$ to $\overline\Omega$ of functions $u\in C^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that
$$
\sup_{|\alpha|\leq k,x\in\mathbb{R}^n}|D^\alpha u(x)|<\infty.
$$
Here $|\alpha|\leq k$ is replaced by $|\alpha|<\infty$ if $k=\infty$.