# Can $C^k(\overline{\Omega})$ functions extend to $C^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, notation

Consider the following definition.

Let the open set $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^n$, and $k$ be a positive integer. $C^k(\Omega)$ will denote the space of functions possessing continuous derivatives up to order $k$ on $\Omega$, and $C^k(\overline{\Omega})$ will denote the space of all $u\in C^k(\Omega)$ such that $\partial^{\alpha}u$ extends continuously to the closure $\overline{\Omega}$ for $0\leq|\alpha|\leq k$.

Here is my **question**:

> If $u\in C^k(\overline{\Omega})$, can $\partial^\alpha u$ extend continuously to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $0\leq|\alpha|\leq k$?

---

This question is motivated by the following ones:

- [Relationship among the function spaces $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$, $C_c^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$ and $C_c^\infty(\Bbb{R}^d)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1561560/9464)
- [What does the notation $C(\bar U)$ mean for $U\subset\Bbb{R}^d$ open?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1425686/9464)
- [Reference request: $C^k(\overline\Omega)$ as restriction of $C^{k}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ functions on $\Omega$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1765356/9464)

Comment: I think the answer is Yes, the proof is similar to the proof in Evans PDE 2nd page.269 (Extension theorem step 2).

Comment: Evans proved the case for $k=1$, but the method are the same in general.

Comment: @yoyo: I don't have any assumptions on $\partial\Omega$ for this question.

Comment: Oh!~~ You are right, the question is more complicated.
Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post has been put as a more complete one in MO:
[Two different kinds of definitions of $C^k(\overline{\Omega})$ — extension and restriction](https://mathoverflow.net/q/250444/14319).

Thanks to a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250444/two-different-kinds-of-definitions-of-ck-overline-omega-extension-and-r#comment615871_250444) there, the answer to the question is yes. But the question in this post does not match the one in the title. See more details in the accepted MO [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/250559/14319).